# Code Not Compiling- Unable to figure out Issue

Tags: python-3.x

I have been stumped on this for days now and I can seem to figure out what the problem is. I am able to run all of it fine except when I select option 1 on the console menu. I will be able to make through the first inputs and then I get an error every time. Also for some reason when another option is selected, it does not jump to that option, it just starts going the password generator code instead. Any help would be appreciated. Still fairly new to all this.

```
import math
import sys
import random
import datetime
import string
import secrets
from datetime import date
while 1:
    print("\nWelcome to the application that will solve your everday problems!")
    print("\nPlease Select an Option from the List Below:")
    print("1: To Generate a New Secure Password ")
    print("2: To Calculate and Format a Percentage ")
    print("3: To Receive the amount of days until Jul 4th, 2025 ")
    print("4: To Calculate the Leg of Triangle by using the Law of Cosines ")
    print("5: To Calculate the Volume of a Right Circular Cylinder ")
    print("6: To Exit the Program ")
    choice = int(input("Please enter your Selected Option: "))
    if choice == 6:
        print("\nThank you for coming, Have a Great Day!")
        break
    elif choice == 1:
        def input_length(message):
            while True:
                try:    #check if input is integer
                    length = int(input(message))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Not an integer! Try again.")
                    continue
                if length < 5:  #check if password's length is greater then 5
                    print("Too short password!")
                    continue
                else:
                    return length
        def input_yes_no(message):
            while True:
                option = input(message).lower()
            if option not in ('y', 'n'):  #check if user entered y/n (or Y/N)
                print("Enter y or n !")
            else:
                return option
        def get_options():
            while True:
                use_upper_case = input_yes_no("Use upper case? [y/n]: ")
                use_lower_case = input_yes_no("Use lower case? [y/n]: ")
                use_numbers = input_yes_no("Use numbers? [y/n]: ")
                use_special_characters = input_yes_no("Use special characters? [y/n]: ")
                options = (use_upper_case, use_lower_case, use_numbers, use_special_characters)
            if all(option == 'n' for option in options): #check if all options are 'n'
                print("Choose some options!")
            elif all(option == 'n' for option in options[:-1]) and options[-1] == 'y':
                print("Password can not contain only special characters")
                 return options
        def generate_alphabet(use_upper_case, use_lower_case, use_numbers, use_special_characters):
            alphabet = '' 
        if use_upper_case == 'y' and use_lower_case == 'y':
            alphabet = string.ascii_letters
        elif use_upper_case == 'y' and use_lower_case == 'n':
             alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
        elif use_upper_case == 'n' and use_lower_case == 'y':
             alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
        if use_numbers == 'y':
             alphabet += string.digits
        if use_special_characters == 'y':
             alphabet += string.punctuation
        def generate_password(alphabet, password_length, options):
            use_upper_case = options[0]
            use_lower_case = options[1]
            use_numbers = options[2]
            use_special_characters = options[3]
        while True: 
            password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(password_length))
            if use_upper_case == 'y':
                if not any(c.isupper() for c in password):
                continue
            if use_lower_case == 'y':
                if not any(c.islower() for c in password):
                continue
            if use_numbers == 'y':
                if not sum(c.isdigit() for c in password) >= 2:
                continue
            if use_special_characters == 'y':
                if not any(c in string.punctuation for c in password):
                continue
            break
        def main():
            password_length = input_length("Enter the length of the password: ")
            options = get_options()
            alphabet = generate_alphabet(*options)
            password = generate_password(alphabet, password_length, options)
            print("Your password is: ", password)
        if __name__ == "__main__":
             main()
    elif choice == 2:
       Num = float(input("Please Enter the Numerator: "))
       Denom = float(input("Please Enter the Denomenator: "))
       Deci = int(input("Please Enter the Number of Decimal Places You Would Like: "))
       Val = Num/Denom*100
       Val = round(Val, Deci)
       print("\nThe Percentage of the numbers you entered is", Val, "%")
    elif choice == 3:
        Today = datetime.date.today()
        Future = date(2025, 7, 25)
        Diff = Future - Today
        print("\nTotal numbers of days till July 4th, 2025 is:", Diff.days)
    elif choice == 4:
        A = int(input("Please Enter angle A: "))
        B = int(input("Please enter angle B: "))
        Angle = int(input("Please Enter the Angle of the Triangle: "))
        c = A*A + B*B - 2*A*B*math.cos(math.pi/180*Angle)
        print("\nThe Leg of the Triangle is:", round(c))
    elif choice == 5:
        Radius = int(input("Please Enter the Radius of the Cylinder: "))
        Height = int(input("Please Enter the Height of the Cylinder: "))
       Volume = (math.pi*Radius*Radius)*Height
       print("\nThe Volume of the Cylinder is:", Volume)
```

Comment: Defining functions in `if` blocks is a strange idea... Start by moving all function definitions to the start of your code, that will make the main structure clearer.

Comment: Ok, I will do that, thank you. I think where I went wrong is that I developed two separate sections of the program separately and then decided to put it together.

Comment: Is your indentation like this in your actual program or is it a copy/pasting error?

Comment: It is not, I had to adjust it a little bit to be able to post it here. I was getting that "Not formatted correctly"  error when trying to post it here.